Unit testing Angular CLI - Karma/jasmine 4.3.5 jasmine component issue
For some reason I cannot make the mock data work. So it can create component

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ListingsService -> AuthService -> MessageService -> MessageService]:

import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'; 

import { ListingsComponent } from './listings.component';
import { dummyListings } from 'src/app/dummy data/dummyListings';
import { dummyUsers } from 'src/app/dummy data/dummyUsers';
import { ListingsService } from 'src/app/services/listings.service';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

class MockJwtHelperService {
 
}

describe('listings Component', () => {
    let component: ListingsComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListingsComponent>;
    let jwtHelper: JwtHelperService;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ListingsComponent],
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [ 
          ListingsService,
          { provide: JwtHelperService, useClass: MockJwtHelperService }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListingsComponent);
      jwtHelper = TestBed.get(MockJwtHelperService);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  
    it('should create the Component', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});

I want my component to be created but i keep getting this error.

Check how MessageService is provided, and import the module which provides it.

Just Mock the MessageService with an empty class and add the methods when you further add test cases:
...
class MockMessageService {
 
}
...

    ...
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ListingsComponent],
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [ 
          ListingsService,
          { provide: JwtHelperService, useClass: MockMessageService },
          { provide: JwtHelperService, useClass: MockJwtHelperService }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
      ...

The above method can also be done for AuthService or even ListingsService.
Another way is to add the MessageService to the providers array, since it's not provided in any module:
    ...
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ListingsComponent],
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [ 
          MessageService,
          ListingsService,
          { provide: JwtHelperService, useClass: MockMessageService },
          { provide: JwtHelperService, useClass: MockJwtHelperService }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
      ...

Finally, we can just provided the MessageService in the root level using providedIn: 'root', this will ensure the service is available without importing anything in the testing file, but it might affect your application, so try this as a last resort.
